# How to change url in open graph options?

Tags: javascript, facebook-opengraph, webapi, share-open-graph

Basically, I'm trying to set up meta tags and all that stuff. I have no idea how to change url so there will be just the name of the website. For instance, github has just GitHub there and I have this long url: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DI6z.png)

I would really appreciate your help.
Thank you

Comment: Try adding <meta property="og:site_name" content="Quote of the Day"> to your header. Check out [ogp.me/](https://ogp.me/) for more info (the site is old, but it includes all of the basic tags).

Comment: @RichDeBourke Yeah, it really worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

By adding `<meta property="og:site_name" content="Quote of the Day">` I was able to change that.